# EF + Automapper, is this a good approach to a ASP.NET MVC 2 web app project?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, automapper

I'm starting a project with MVC 2 and would like to know if the following structure is a good approach in terms of design.

Currently I have divided my web app in two projects

-ApplicationModelLayer (library project)

- Models

Here I have one class for each entity of my database where I'll write validations and business logic. When I do CRUD operations, I call Automapper to do the mapping: MyModelClass -> EFClass.

-ApplicationViewLayer (MVC 2 web project)

- Controllers
- Views

Am I applying a good design and separation of the ApplicationModelLayer ?
Is this *"better"* than using just EF with partial classes to do the validation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put the view model classes and the mappings between the EF models and the view models inside the ApplicationViewLayer. Because view models are specifically designed for the requirements of a view I would use the `Models` folder of the web application to store them.

As far as the model layer is concerned, in the addition to the `Models` folder, I would have a `Repositories` and `Services` folders. The `Repositories` is for CRUD operations with the EF domain models and `Services` should contain the business logic and more complex operations with the domain models based on the simple CRUD operations.

In the web tier a controller action will consume a service operation to fetch a domain model, map this domain model using AutoMapper to a view model and pass the view model to the view. And the other way round: a controller action could receive a view model from the view, use AutoMapper to map it back to a domain model and pass this model to the service layer for processing.